# How can i use a property inside a yaml file as an argument to a method inside a controller?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, yaml

I'm working with some files and i need to pass some yaml file properties in a method inside and controller, but i can't, it always return "undefined method for a nil class"

```
def method
  yml_import 
  variable = class.other_method('action', @yaml_file['index']['property'])
end

private

def yml_import
  @yaml_file = YAML.load_file(File.join("path to file.yml"))
end
```

I expected the variable to get the string that is within the property of the yaml file but it doesn't. Returns me "undefined method for nil class".

```
def method
  yml_import if conditional
  var1 = class.new('args') #this is ok this part was already functioning
  var2 = var1.other_method('action', @yaml_file['index']['property']) # this line is the cursed 
end
```

Comment: If so, the error has nothing to do with the YAML file. It says undefined method for `nil` object. If you're invoking `other_method` in `class`, then `class` is `nil`. Can you add the "real" code or another way the whole stack trace of your error?

Comment: of course i can! Thank you for the help before everything!

Comment: def method
       yml_import
       if conditional
                 var1 = class.new('args')#this is ok this part was already functioning
                 var2 = var1.other_method('action', @yaml_file['index']['property']#this line is the cursed

Comment: Is `other_method ` defined somewhere? What's the value of `var1` at that point?

Comment: the other_method is a default method defined previously and the value or var1 is a robot for data scrapping

Comment: Try checking if `var1` implements that method: `var1.respond_to?(:other_method)`.

Comment: Checked! It responds. Do you know any post or guide to use yaml files properties as methods arguments?

Comment: Really it doesn't depend on file formats, but in passing values. Your method must be defined to accept n arguments, so you should pass them. What's the whole stacktrace of the error you're getting (copy-paste without omitting lines).

Comment: Have you checked the value of what's returned from the YAML file by doing a `puts @yaml_file['index']['property']`? Is that `nil`?